# Is there any api for pollution index like weather?

Tags: api

am working on a project which requires me to get the pollution index based on a location. Are there any services online that can provide on demand pollution index?

I googled it but could not find anything.

Any suggestions?

THanks

Comment: It seems to be hard to Google because API stands also for Air Pollution Index. :)

Answer (score 3):

The EnviroFacts 'Toxic Release Inventory' API publishes data about toxins released into the environment in the US: http://www.epa.gov/developer/efapi_tri.html

Answer (score 0):

http://www.epa.gov/air/emissions/where.htm seems to have a lot of info on emissions (by state or pollutant), but not the Air Pollution Index specifically... According to Wikipedia the Air Pollution Index only covers China, Hong Kong, and Malaysia, so I'm not sure where you're located but it doesn't seem like there's an American equivalent.

Comment: Not sure if this is true, but customeweather.com is going to add an API to their feeds